# TreeMap<?,?> cannot be converted to TreeMap<String,Double>?

Tags: java, treemap

I am practicing with TreeMap in java and I am stucked in a situation where I have to use TreeMap constructor, I am not able to find any way dealing with it, I am writing the part of program here, can anyone help me out with this?
what should this function return and how do I deal with

Error: java.util.TreeMap<capture#1 of ?,capture#2 of ?> cannot be converted to java.util.TreeMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Double>

```
   public TreeMap<?,?> createMatchesMap(String cricketDataset)
    {
           
        TreeMap<String,Double> tm = new TreeMap<String,Double>();
               String[] str = cricketDataset.split("\\|");
               for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
                   String[] str1 = str[i].split(",");
                   Double c = 0.0;
                   int c1=0;
                   if(str1[0].equals("1")) {
                       
                   for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++) {
                       String[] str2 = str[j].split(",");
                       if(str2[1].equals(str1[1]) && str2[0].equals("1")) {
                           Double score = Double.parseDouble(str2[2]);
                           c=c+score;
                           c1+=1;
                       }
                   }
                   tm.put(str1[1],c/c1);
                   }
               }
            return tm;
   }
```

Comment: Why not make the return type `TreeMap<String, Double>`?

Comment: I cannot make return type as this, because in the test class..there is constructor asTreeMap<?,?> only and there the error is of type mismatch with TreeMap<String,Double>

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with covariance and contravariance (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). In short if you could do this:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> lo = ls;
```

then you could do this in the next step

```
lo.add(new Double(1.3));
```

which would add a Double to our list of strings (as lo refers to the same object as ls)